# how to get into LogIn form - if there isnt any key press in my C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Login form and Main form in my C# WinForm program.

When I'm in the Main form and the user doesn't press any key or move the mouse for 5 minutes - I want to go to Login form.

How to do it in C# WinForm ?

thanks in advance

Comment: This is what the Windows screen saver does.  Don't try to replace it, your program hasn't been subjected to a million hackers that tried to break it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a small sample to show you how to implement user activity detection on complete application level. The trick is in using application message filters.

This example will raise message when user is not active for 5 minutes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {

        private static Timer _idleTimer;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            _idleTimer = new Timer();
            _idleTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_idleTimer_Tick);
            _idleTimer.Interval = (5 * 60) * 1000; // (5 minutes * seconds) * milliseconds

            Application.AddMessageFilter(new MouseMessageFilter(UserIsActive));
            Application.AddMessageFilter(new KeyboardMessageFilter(UserIsActive));

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static void _idleTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are idle for " + _idleTimer.Interval.ToString() + " milliseconds");
        }

        static void UserIsActive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _idleTimer.Stop();
            _idleTimer.Start();
        }

        public class MouseMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
        {
            private EventHandler _callback;

            public MouseMessageFilter(EventHandler callback)
            {
                _callback = callback;
            }

            private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

            public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
                {
                    _callback(null, null);
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        private class KeyboardMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
        {
            private EventHandler _callback;

            public KeyboardMessageFilter(EventHandler callback)
            {
                _callback = callback;
            }

            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
            const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;

            #region IMessageFilter Members

            public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
            {
                if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                {
                    _callback(null, null);
                }

                if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) || (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYUP))
                {
                    _callback(null, null);
                }

                return false;
            }

            #endregion
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just use one IMessageFilter, it handles both mouse and keyboard messages.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it works even if i press any key or move the mouse

Comment: @Gali: You are welcome. What @Hans Passant wanted to say is that mouse and keyboard could be handled in only one MessageFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Put a Timer on the form and have it Do the Right Thing, whatever that is (close current form, clear fields, etc.)

Comment: but how to measure 5 minutes after the last key press or mouse move ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty base class (inherited from the Form class override the onkeypress and onmousemove events in this class) for all your application forms and create a timer instance in the constructor of the base form and set the timer interval to 5 mins in there and perform any necessary cleanup, if possible! Make sure rest all your forms inherit from this base class with timer and you are done. Or else you'll end up writing/modifying all the forms in your application for adding a timer and setting an interval!

Note: This will be helpful when you have lots of forms in your application! If you have a couple of them, then it is alright, if you go to each and add a timer and set an interval and write some common code to cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) and set it, say, for 5 seconds. Then you have a property that says when was the last time user pressed a key or moved the mouse (you set this property in the proper event handlers: [`Form.KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) and [`Form.MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx)). If the timer ticks and the time since the last user action is more than 5 minutes, you can log out the current user.

But this doesn't look like a very useful feature to me and I think it's pretty much just an annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create Windows Hook for input messages. Each time you receive a mouse or keyboard message, restart your timer. When the timer elapses, logout the user.

[This MSDN Mag article about using Windows Hooks in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx) should help.