# login timeout winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, login-script

Can anyone tell me, how to make a Login timedout functionality in my Winform application. My user is able to login. What I want to do is, if he doesn't touch the application for say 20 min, and then he try to access anything in the application he will have to fill the password in it first.

Sorry for not providing any code, as I dont have idea where to start. And I believe for Login its simple SQL Query to check the Username and Password. 
I work in C# and SqlServer 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/1e1d2487-482f-4fab-add7-6a359b730912/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get into LogIn form - if there isnt any key press in my C# program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477939/how-to-get-into-login-form-if-there-isnt-any-key-press-in-my-c-sharp-program)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/815cfbf9-2303-4637-a7c2-d25ef5c1eeb3/

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `System.Timers.Timer` for waiting for 20 min, and then just call the logout method (you should make one - it should null the connection). When he 'touches' the app, just show him the login form or message him that he's not logged in