# Execute function if no user action was performed after certain time

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a simple way how to implement function (in `Form_Activated` or `Form_Load`) that if no action was performed by user after certain time app will automaticly switch to defaulf form? Let's say user log in(form change) and then he do nothing and I want system after 30 seconds automaticly execute "log out" function - go back to default form.

Comment: and what you have tried????

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626454/timer-to-close-the-application

Comment: Timer maybe??? There's a clue in the name there...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477939/how-to-get-into-login-form-if-there-isnt-any-key-press-in-my-c-sharp-program

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have to implement this on your own. 
Implement a property "LastUserAction" or something in your class, which needs to be updated each time, when the user performs an action.
Then implement a timer or a thread, which checks all the time, if the last user action is older than 30 secs. If true, perform Application.Exit() or form closing.