# Disable buttons after after 10 seconds of inactivity using timer

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to disable all buttons I am using after a time period of inactivity using the timer from toolbox. I can currently get it to work by just disabling the relevant buttons in

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

but this disables in ten seconds regardless of activity or inactivity.
Is it possible for the timer to work only after 10 seconds of no activity?

Here is the code I am using.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    button4.Enabled = false;
    button5.Enabled = false;
    button6.Enabled = false;
    button7.Enabled = false;
    button8.Enabled = false;
    button9.Enabled = false;
    button10.Enabled = false;
    button11.Enabled = false;
    button12.Enabled = false;
    button13.Enabled = true;
    button14.Enabled = true;
    button14.Visible = false;
    button15.Enabled = true;
    button15.Visible = false;
    button17.Enabled = false;
    button17.Visible = false;
    button18.Visible = false;
    button19.Visible = false;
    button20.Enabled = false;
    textBox1.Visible = false;
    textBox2.Visible = false;
    textBox3.Visible = false;
    textBox4.Visible = false;
    checkBox1.Visible = false;
    checkBox2.Visible = false;
    label15.Visible = false;
    label16.Visible = false;
    label21.Visible = false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Just reset the timer each time your user is active (e.g. moves the mouse or presses a key).

Comment: Better to come up with client side JS solution.

Comment: @Amit This looks like a Windows app, not a web app

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute function if no user action was performed after certain time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389486/execute-function-if-no-user-action-was-performed-after-certain-time)

Comment: Hi @thumbmunkeys. What I mean my inactivity is when no buttons are clicked for 10 seconds. It will be longer than 10 seconds. Im just using 10 seconds for testing purposes.

Comment: Could you provide the piece of code where you are defing your timer?

Comment: Reset the timer in the Click event handler for for each button and you should get what you need

Comment: @Eim then you need to restart the timer each time a button is clicked (as germi said)

Comment: Checkout GetLastInputInfo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidG- Ok. In that case for every activity timer needs to reset.

Comment: Thanks all. I will try and restart the timer each time a button is clicked. thanks again.

Comment: Apart from your actual question.., If you want all of your conrtols (buttons, labels, etc) to be `Enabled = False;` you can simply have a function with a loop, which FindControls in the form and disable them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following event to each button that might be clicked and be counted as 'active':

```
public void ResetTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Start();
}

...

button1.Click += ResetTimer;
```

The `Timer` in Winforms doesn't have a `Reset` method (nor does any of the other timer classes), so you'll have to stop it first and then start it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Reset Time every time user click any button.

**Solution 2**:  ( Not Recommended )

Have a global variable LastActiveTime, Every-time somebody clicks any
button :

```
 LastActiveTime = DateTime.Now()
```

Parallel running Timer/Thread will check every second if inactive time is more than 10
second and will do accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time. I have it working now.